# How to validate the expiration date of a self signed SSL certificate used for Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, ssl-certificate

I'm have a self signed certificate (and private key) in my possession.
They are used for Kafka SSL authentication. 
How can I know what is the validity (expiration) of my certificate ?

Iv'e tried looking on the instructions to create the certificate but couldn't find a good indication for an answer. 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/security_tutorial.html#generating-keys-certs